# One definition for different files

Tags: preamble

I am new in LaTeX and have one question:

I have different files, that all should have the same "definition". With "definition" I mean the following lines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Montpellier}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}

\author{Max Mustermann}
\date{\today}

%....
```

If I copy this in each file and want to edit something, I would have to edit it in every file..

Is there a better way to define it only once and use it in multiple files.

Comment: Yes: make it a `.sty`, say `fiddledeedee.sty`, save it in the same directory as the other files, and in each file (or in the main file) write `\usepackage{fiddledeedee}`. Unrelated: I recommend loading `xcolor`  rather than `color`. It is much more powerful, and can use colours by name.

Comment: Or put the stuff (except the document class) in a `tex` file and use `\input{SunBolderName/myDefinition.tex}`.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner using a `.sty` extension is more idiomatically laetx than using `.sty`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had to look up *idiomatically* :)

Comment: Omg, **SunBolderName** is supposed to be **SubFolderName**. It was apparently too late for me :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner well you were lucky I spelt it more accurately than my spelling of latex, otherwise the lookup would have been harder:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My brain did a auto correct in your case :)